# Amazon S3 - Transfer utility won't work in paralel

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I'm trying to upload multiple files to `S3` using the `TransferUtility` class from `Amazon SDK` for `.NET`

My thinking was, that since the SDK doesn't allow to upload multiple files form different folders at once, I'd create multiple threads and upload there, but it looks like Amazon SDK has some kind of checking against this, since I don't notice any parallel execution of my uploading method.

Here is the pseudo-code I'm using:

```
int totalUploaded = 0;
foreach (var dItem in Detection.Items.AsParallel())
{
    UploadFile(dItem);
    totalUploaded++;

    Action a = () => { lblStatus.Text = $"Uploaded {totalUploaded} from {Detection.ItemsCount}"; };
    BeginInvoke(a);
}
```

I'm using `.AsParallel` to spawn multiple threads. My CPU (`i7-5930K`) has 6 cores and supports multi-threading, so `AsParallel` must spawn more threads as needed.

And here is the upload method

```
private void UploadFile(Detection.Item item)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Enter " + item.FileInfo);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadsCount);

...

        using (var client = AmazonS3Client)
        {

        ....

            // if we are here we need to upload
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                Key = s3Key,
                BucketName = settings.BucketName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                FilePath = item.FileInfo.FullName,
                ContentType = "image/png",
            };

            TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
            utility.Upload(request);
        }
}
```

Сan't see what can be wrong here? Any idea highly appreciated.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are only constructing the `ParallelEnumerable`, but treat it like a simple `IEnumerable`:

```
foreach (var dItem in Detection.Items.AsParallel())
```

This part of code simply iterates over collection. In case you want the **parallel** executing, you have to use the extension method [`ForAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383744.aspx):

```
Detection.Items.AsParallel().ForAll(dItem  =>
{
    //Do parallel stuff here
});
```

Also you can simply use the [`Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) class:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Detection.Items, dItem => 
{
    //Do parallel stuff here
});
```

Comment: oh wow, I've been using such construction for a long, was always thinking that foreach would get transformed in more threads, what a dummy :) Thank you, now it works as needed.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it inly provides an opportunity to execute next `LINQ` extension methods in parallel. Good luck, and don't forget change other places with similar construction!